# importing excel DB to SPSS

Tags: excel, spss

hey, I have a little bizzare quastion...
i have excel DB that is arrange a little wired, its looks like this :

[image]

my quastion is , are this type of DB works for SPSS ? is it possible to do statistic analysis based on this type of input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read about pivot tables in excel. You can normalize your data with it. Then export pivot table to csv, which can be imported to SPSS.

Comment: i know about PT option, i wander if their is an "code" or a "script" or a simple action in the SPSS that make this possible automaticly...

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial shows how to  [Prepare Data for Import into SPSS](http://www.stattutorials.com/SPSS/TUTORIAL-SPSS-Prepare-Data-Excel.htm)

hope this helps you,